# Matrix addition - can a 3x2 matrix + a 2x3 matrix be added together?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have two matrices;

$$ 1) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    3 & -2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    0 & -3\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

And
$$ 2) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    4 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

But can these two be added together, is this possible?
I found [from this PDF](http://www2.hawaii.edu/%7Ejanst/141/lecture/19-Matrices.pdf) the following quote:

The sum A + B of two matrices A, B (which
must have the same number of rows, and the
same number of columns) is the matrix (also
with the same shape) given by adding
corresponding elements of A and B.

This suggests to me that I cannot add together Matrix 1 and 2, but I can however add together Matrix 2 and a third matrix with the same dimentions, for example:

$$ 3) 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

I've come to believe that I can add up Matrix 2+3 but not Matrix 1+2 or 1+3 for instance.
Am I correct in my assumptions here?

And would this differ in any way if i try to multiply the matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't add two matrices if they don't have the same dimension. In your case,
$$\left(
\begin{matrix}
    -2 & 1 & 3 \\
    4 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}
\right) + \left(
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)=\left(
\begin{matrix}
    -2+2 & 1+1 & 3+(-1) \\
    4+(-1) & 3+0 & 2+3 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)=\left(
\begin{matrix}
    0 & 2 & 2 \\
    3 & 3 & 5 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

As you can see, adding two matrices is the same as adding its elements. If we talk about multiplication, things change considerably. I recommend you this [link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html), which is very instructive.

Comment: Thank you that was a very helpful and quick response, I will look into the link you gave me. I also see that Khan academy has a lot of helpful stuff but I wast not able to find a an answer there about whether I could add together two matrices with different dimensions.